# Kubernetes pods on failure perform some action

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, kubernetes-pod

I have a requirement of executing a sql query if some pod goes down . I wish to update records in database against the hostname of that pod , How can I possibly achieve this what are ways to do this?

Comment: Do you want to run the SQL query inside the pod being deleted (risky ...) or (hopefully) outside ?

Comment: Outside the pod the db is not on any pod

Comment: Your environment would be in cloud or local environment? What k8s version are you using. Does Arghya Sadhu answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a handler in the application code which handles `SIGTERM` signal and make an entry to the DB. A `SIGTERM` signal is sent by kubernetes to the running pod before a `SIGKILL` is sent after the grace period mentioned by `terminationGracePeriodSeconds`.

As an alternative and safer approach you can offload this responsibility to another application which periodically polls a health-check endpoint exposed by the other app.The health check endpoint can expose the hostname of the app. When health-check fails make an entry to DB.

Comment: In case of SIGTERM I don't think it will take care of force shutdowns right ?

Comment: Yeah force shutdown is not taken care...in that case alternative is safer approach

Comment: But the alternative wont work in our case since the pods are load balanced and connecting directly to a pod wont be encouraged

Comment: You could do push based where the app pushes some heart beat periodically instead of some other app connecting and pulling information

Comment: Right had it in mind just was looking if  kubernetes can have something which helps me here

Comment: Your application will be more portable and generic if it is not aware that it runs inside Kubernetes. This is in general a good practice not to make an application dependant to the underlying platform, here k8s. So, if possible, I propose you avoid any solution that get the list of running pods from k8s api server, using a k8s client running inside a montoring pod. So above track (heart beat) LGTM.